# Holding the mouse button automatically on OSX

Tags: mac, mouse

Is there some sort of app that will let me, preferably toggleable with a keyboard shortcut, hold down the left mouse button? (Not click fast, just hold down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the default double tap to drag work for you? You can enable it in System Preferences>Universal Access:

[image]

Comment: Great idea, works perfectly!

Comment: @JJ56 Awesome! (would you upvote the answer too? Thanks!)

Comment: I have enabled "Dragging (with Drag Lock)" but when i double-tap, nothing happens.  It's as if the left mouse button isn't being held down at all!

Comment: Doesn't work in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

*The accepted answer from 2012 is obsolete.  Use the following for Mac OS X:*

## Mac OS X

System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Enable Mouse Keys

> Mouse Keys allows the mouse pointer to be controlled using the keyboard number pad.

### What if I don't have a "keyboard number pad"?

> If you use a laptop that does not have a numeric keypad, you can still the Mouse Keys feature, but you will need to press the Num Lock key first. Once you have turned on the Num Lock, use the keys with the small numbers on them to control the pointer. The I key will perform a mouse click.

http://etc.usf.edu/techease/4all/input-devices/what-are-mouse-keys/

#### What if I don't have a "Num Lock"?

I give up.  Search the Apple Store or Google for a 3rd part app.